get a controller method name in a Spring filter
I have a SpringBoot 2.6.14 WebApp and I'm using a Spring OncePerRequestFilter to log some information about the HTTP request and response.
The code is similar to the follow one:
@Slf4j(topic = "logger")
public class LoggingFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

  private final ObjectMapper mapper;

  public LoggingFilter(ObjectMapper mapper) {
      super();
      this.mapper = mapper;
  }

  @Override
  protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    
    ContentCachingRequestWrapper requestWrapper = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(request);
    ContentCachingResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(response);

    ......

}

I manage to log the uri, the type of request (GET,POST ecc..) the host and some other usefull info but I can not manage to retrieve the Controller signature, or simply the name. Googling around I read that I can achieve this with an HandlerInterceptor but I must use a filter.
For example if I have a Controller like the follow one:
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class SomeController {

  @GetMapping("/all")
  public ResponseEntity<List<Some>> findAll() {
      List<Some> result = service.findAll();
      return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
  }
}

and I call it I can retrieve the path /api/v1/all but I would like to obtain even the findAll() method name.
Is it possible without the HandlerInterceptor?

Yes you can if you get the HandlerMapping and use it to resolve the handler it is going to use. Drawback you will resolve the handler twice due to the DispatcherServlet doing the same thing again. So you will get a performance hit. Why wouldn't you be able to use a HandlerInterceptor?

I cannot use HandlerInterceptor because off my boss wants to use filters.. anyway can you provide a code example please?

Tell your boss that it isn't possible without a filter.

However it is possible!
Here my complete solution..
filter class configuration:
@Configuration
public class FilterConfig {

  @Bean
  @ConditionalOnWebApplication(type = ConditionalOnWebApplication.Type.SERVLET)
  FilterRegistrationBean<LoggingFilter> logFilter(DispatcherServlet dispatcher) {
     FilterRegistrationBean<LoggingFilter> registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
     registrationBean.setFilter(new LoggingFilter(dispatcher));
     registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/api/v1/test/*");
     registrationBean.setOrder(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE);
     return registrationBean;
  }

}

The Filter:
@Slf4j(topic = "filter")
public class LoggingFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

  private final DispatcherServlet dispatcher;

  public LoggingFilter(DispatcherServlet dispatcher) {
    super();
    this.dispatcher = dispatcher;
  }

  @Override
  protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    
    ContentCachingRequestWrapper requestWrapper = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(request);
    ContentCachingResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(response);
    ......
    filterChain.doFilter(requestWrapper, responseWrapper);

    ServletRequestPathUtils.parseAndCache(request);
    
    List<HandlerMapping> mapping = dispatcher.getHandlerMappings();
    List<HandlerExecutionChain> chain = new ArrayList<>();
    mapping.forEach(item -> {
        try {
            HandlerExecutionChain c = item.getHandler(requestWrapper);
            chain.add(c);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e);
        }
    });
    
    List<HandlerExecutionChain> resource = chain.stream().filter(i -> i != null).collect(Collectors.toList());
    HandlerExecutionChain hEc = resource.stream().findFirst().orElse(null);
    HandlerMethod handlerMethod = (HandlerMethod) hEc.getHandler();
    Method method = handlerMethod.getMethod(); // All INFO about the method called by request
    
    log.info(method.getName()); // method name
    ......
    responseWrapper.copyBodyToResponse();

}

Maybe is not completely compliant but if you can't register an interceptor this is a way to achieve the result.
Hope helps.
